If an object is accelerating when it enters water, will the buoyant force change?
If an object is accelerating when it enters water, will the buoyant force equation be changed to $B = V\rho(g + \text{acceleration})$? Or will it remain the same?

Assuming Ideal liquid
No, the buoyant force expression will remain same as it depends on the acceleration of liquid. magnitude and direction of buoyant force is completely independent of the motion of body. It depends only on the volume of the body immersed in the liquid, density of liquid and the acceleration of the liquid.
So as long as the liquid is at rest Buoyant Force ($B$)$=V\rho g$ in an inertial frame. In an accelerating frame it can vary depending on the relative motion of frame and liquid

Thank you! Just for clarity, the Buoyant force of an object is the same for an object floating in water compared to the object accelerating into the water greater than g.
But wouldnt the force impacted on the object be greater as the Mass of Water is displaced more rapidly?
Thanks!

Buoyant force depends on the mass of water displaced and not the rate at which it is displaced so as long as the immersed volume is same and density of liquid is uniform acceleration of the object won't be affecting it

even if the object is moving at constant velocity in the liquid, the buoyant force will change relative to static equilibrium because the pressure distribution surrounding the object will change.

@ChetMiller I assumed liquid to be ideal

Thanks for articulating that assumption.  Maybe you can included it in the Answer.

@ChetMiller yeah I did after you pointed that out
